# How to get keys from the following json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

[image]

I am working with handsontable with a php backend. i am tring to dynamically create table column headers so I can create an array of column names which I can feed into handsontable using:

```
colHeaders: ['ID', 'First', 'Last Name', 'Address'],
```

I've included a sample of JSON produced at backend in the screenshot. How do I create get the keys so I can create the colHeaders array? i've tried:

```
 var keys = res.keys();
```

My load function is:

```
            $parent.find('button[name=load]').click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                url: "AjaxController/tableLoad/"+tablename,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (res) {

                    var keys = res.keys();
                    console.log(keys);


                    // create js title array from 1st row data
//                      colHeaders: ['ID', 'First', 'Last Name', 'Address'],
//                      handsontable.colHeaders: keys;
                  handsontable.loadData(res);
                  $console.text('Data loaded');
                  console.log(res)
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to get the keys of an object as follows:

```
var keys = $.map(res, function(element,key) { return key; });
```

However for the sample you've provided, an array of objects, you would use the following:

```
var keys = $.map(res[0], function(element,key) { return key; }); 
//RESULT: ["id", "name", "description"]
```

Comment: I ended up using this.

Comment: Great! Glad it was of help :) Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

For a valid `JSON` use `Object.keys(object),` to get its keys which returns an `iterable` object.

```
var keys = Object.keys(res);
```

Comment: Object.keys is IE9+. Add a polyfill if you need to support IE8 or older. There's one on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys